# XML chart data to html

Tags: python, html, xml, powerpoint

I have a list of embedded excel data in a pptx that can be extracted automatically by changing the file type to '.zip'.

The corresponding data is in XML format. The goal is to use this XML file to plot in HTML. Any suggestions are appreciated.

**My code so far just list all the contents :**

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parseXML(xmlfile):
    print(ET.tostring(root,encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))

items = parseXML('chart1.xml')
```

Comment: You'll need to decide on a plotting package and see what its data requirements are. Then you could use python or a templating system like jinja2 or xslt to transform the data to what you want. Because there are so many choices, this is too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Say more about what the "list of embedded excel data" is. If you just want to extract the data points contained in a chart in a .pptx file, you can use `python-pptx` for that https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html. That would be something like `presentation.slides[0].shapes[0].chart.series[0].values`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to first convert the data in JSON format.